# Replacing a sub string without inbuilt function (Python)

Tags: python, function, replace, find, substring

So I am writing a code for a school project however, I want to do it without any inbuild function but I am stuck at the find fucntion. This is how far I have done. The question is,

> Write a Python program to find the first appearance of the substring 'too' and
> 'good' from a given string. If 'good' follows the 'too', replace the whole 'too'' good'
> substring with 'excellent' and print the resulting string. If the above does not
> appear, print the string as it is.

```
user_string = input()
sub = "too good"
rep_sub = "excellent"
low = user_string.find(sub)
high = low + len(sub)
if sub in user_string:
    replaced_string = user_string[:low] + rep_sub + user_string[high:]
    print(replaced_string)
else:
    print(user_string)
```

Comment: You're supposed to look for the first occurrences of `too` and `good` separately.

Comment: Loop through the string character by character. If you find the first character of `sub`, check if the following slice of the string matches the rest of `sub`.

Comment: `if user_string[i:i+len(sub)] == sub:`

Comment: What do you consider builtin functions? Is ``str.find`` a builtin function for you? What about ``str.__getitem__``, i.e. indexing and slicing?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi He apparently considers `find` a bulitin, since he says he's having trouble replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the indexes of the string. At each point, check if the following slice matches the substring you're searching for.

```
def find(string, substring):
    strlen = len(string)
    sublen = len(substring)
    if strlen >= sublen:
        for i in range(strlen - sublen):
            if string[i:i+sublen] == substring:
                return i
    return -1 # means not found
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion here:

```
def replace(string, sub_str, rpl_str):
    if sub_str not in strong:
        return string

    low = string.find(sub_str)  # lowest index of substring
    high = low + len(sub_str)  # highest index of substring
return replace(string[:low] + rpl_str + string[high:], sub_str, rpl_str)
```